# Improving my greedy Algorithm

Tags: java, arrays

**This is my code that look a way to find a sum in an array **

```
     public class Piecedemonei {
        public static void recherche(int[] tab) {
                int num;
                int quo;

                for (int i = 0; i <= tab.length - 1; i++) {


 int somme = 18;
                    System.out.println("Solution  " + i);

                    for (int j = i; j < tab.length; j++){


                        if (tab[j] <= somme) {

                            num = somme / tab[j];
                            System.out.print(num+"*" + " " + tab[j]);
                            System.out.println(" ");

                            somme -= num * tab[j];
        j=0;
                        }



                }
            }
            }




            public static void main(String[] args) {
                int aba[] = { 7, 6, 4, 5 };
                recherche(aba);
                System.out.println();

            }

        }
```

**Output**

```
Solution  0
2 7 + 1 4
Solution  1
Solution  2
Solution  3
```

**I am looking a way to improve my code so that the output looks like this : **

```
 Solution  0
2*7 + 1*4
Solution  1
3*6
Solution  2
4*4 + 1*4
Solution  3
```

**Why cant I reset my loop so that it does the same thing again and again ? **

Comment: Why cant I reset my loop so that it does the same thing again and again : You need to declare 'somme' inside the first for-loop. Otherwise, the following loops never gets in "if (tab[j] <= somme)"

Comment: You code looks for somme=18, but you decrement in the inner loop. You need to reassign somme=18 at the start of every loop

Comment: added an answer with formatting, easier to see.

Comment: you also need to start the 2nd loop at i, not 0. Otherwise, you are just redoing the same calculation everytime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
int somme = 18;
for (int i = 0; i <= tab.length - 1; i++) {
    System.out.println("Solution  " + i);

    for (int j = 0; j < tab.length; j++){
    ...
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i <= tab.length - 1; i++) {
    int somme = 18;
    System.out.println("Solution  " + i);

    for (int j = i; j < tab.length; j++) {
    ...
```

Notice the `int j = i` in the inner loop.

Comment: Thank you so much ! oh my god , how did you figure maybe there is a way you understand this?

Comment: Practice, practice, practice :)